# 500 error preg_replace_callback when using function ($match) use ($video){}

Tags: php-5.3, preg-replace-callback

Works on my localhost running php 5.3.4

Does not work on my VPS hostgator account running 5.3.6

The problem here seems to be the "use" keyword

**Code Below**

```
<?php

$video = $this->Video;

$post['Post']['body'] =
    preg_replace_callback("/\[\[audio=(.*)\]\]/", function ($match) use ($video) {
        return $video->show(array('video' => $match[1]));
    }, $post['Post']['body']);

?>
```

Many thanks for you help.

Comment: Works fine on my Windows PHP/5.3.5. What's the error? Syntax? **edit** Are you sure your VPS has PHP >= 5.3? Print `PHP_VERSION` to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I am certain. I ran phpinfo to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had our server admin update the server to 5.3.8 and everything works as normal. Not sure what the problem really was.